# How do I go about identifying all the plants in my backyard?

Tags: identification, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you identify a plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-do-you-identify-a-plant)

I just moved to a new place but do not know what all plants are there in my small backyard.

How can I identify them all?