# What is this tropical-style houseplant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I am not at all trained in identifying plants. I've tried the tips from the question: [How do you identify a plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-do-you-identify-a-plant), but I have no idea what kind of group or family this plant belongs to, so starting a search is difficult. Google Image Search yields no results.

So my question is: can somebody identify this plant? It grows quite well in a tropical climate is all that I can say about it. And it measures about 70cm in height.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm limited in the option to post links, so here is another link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7VQ3p.jpg, and this is the link of the other related post: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-do-you-identify-a-plant

Answer (score 6):

Just a wild guess, but I would guess a Pilidendron, maybe Philodendron martianum.

Comment: I agree, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philodendron_martianum